# Can I use modernizr.js or respond.js without using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working on one project where I can't use jQuery. But I have to support HTML5 and CSS3 elements for IE8 browser.

My question is can I use [modernizr.js](http://modernizr.com/) or [respond.js](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/respond.js/) without using jquery

Answer (score 1):

modernizr.js and respond.js seem to be pure JavaScript libraries, so YES you can use them without jquery!